# Correct declaration syntax in Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm new to Arduino and I borrowed this code from http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Basics-Making-Sound/step2/Playing-A-Melody/

When I try to verify the code, I get

```
error: expected declaration before '}' token
```

on the last line. How can I fix it? Again, I am new to this so if you need more details let me know.

```
#include "pitch.h"

// notes in the melody:
int melody[] = {NOTE_C4, NOTE_G3,NOTE_G3, NOTE_A3, NOTE_G3,0, NOTE_B3, NOTE_C4};

// note durations: 4 = quarter note, 8 = eighth note, etc.:
int noteDurations[] = {
4, 8, 8, 4,4,4,4,4 };

  void setup() {
  // iterate over the notes of the melody:
    for (int thisNote = 0; thisNote < 8; thisNote++) {

    // to calculate the note duration, take one second
    // divided by the note type.
    //e.g. quarter note = 1000 / 4, eighth note = 1000/8, etc.
    int noteDuration = 1000/noteDurations[thisNote];
    tone(8, melody[thisNote],noteDuration);

    // to distinguish the notes, set a minimum time between them.
    // the note's duration + 30% seems to work well:
    int pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * 1.30;
    delay(pauseBetweenNotes);
    // stop the tone playing:
    noTone(8);
    }
  }

  void loop() {
  // no need to repeat the melody.
  }
}
```

Comment: You should learn C++ beforehand, btw.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You got any suggestions on how to fix this particular problem though?

Comment: The indentation of your setup() and loop() functions suggests that they're nested inside something, but they're not (and as far as I know they don't need to be). That may be what led to the extra `}`. I suggest shifting the functions 2 columns left, so they're aligned with the declarations of `melody` and `noteDurations`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extraneous closing brace `}` at the end of the code. Remove the one in the last line, it's not needed.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. The last line of my code has a close-bracket. Is that the line you are referring to?

Comment: What the heck. I wrote "semi-colon". Silly me. Thanks @KeithThompson for the edit.